# How do I delete duplicate columns in SQLite using CTE - error

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-delete

I have a database with a table called 'Link' which has 'Ex_ID' and 'Cat_ID' which has duplicate rows. I looked up how to delete these duplicates and came up with this code:

```
WITH LinkCTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ex_ID, Cat_ID 
    ORDER BY Ex_ID, Cat_ID) as RowNumber
    FROM Link
)
DELETE FROM LinkCTE WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

But it gave me this error:

```
-- At line 1:
WITH LinkCTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ex_ID, Cat_ID 
    ORDER BY Ex_ID, Cat_ID) as RowNumber
    FROM Link
)
DELETE FROM LinkCTE WHERE RowNumber > 1
-- Result: no such table: LinkCTE
```

I then added 'SELECT * FROM LinkCTE;' before the delete and the table looks fine but it still gives me an error after:

```
-- At line 7:
DELETE FROM LinkCTE WHERE RowNumber > 1
-- Result: no such table: LinkCTE
```

I don't know why it can't find 'LinkCTE'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't delete directly from a CTE in SQLite.
If you want to delete duplicate rows per `Ex_ID` and `Cat_ID` and keep just 1 row you can do it by using the column [`ROWID`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html):

```
DELETE FROM Link 
WHERE ROWID NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(ROWID) 
  FROM Link 
  GROUP BY Ex_ID, Cat_ID
);
```